# How to make a categorical grouped scatterplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this idea in mind for a plot and I am really struggling, with not knowing where to start. There are some ingenious people here so lets try this one.

[image]

How to make a plot like this in pgfplot? An example would be really helpful, I can figure out the rest. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a way to plot multiple y-values for same x-value ?

Comment: sort of, but then how to add the categories?

Comment: What do you mean by categories?

Comment: The labels on the X-axis...

Comment: That can be done with `symbolic x` option in `pgfplots`

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, I do not now what samples you are plotting here, so I just made something up. Apart from that, it is not too difficult to come up with something that resembles your screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
f(\x,\y)=(\x-0.5)*exp(-\y*\x*\x);},font=\sffamily]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=60,xtick={1,2,3,4},xticklabels={Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun},
ytick={0,10,...,60},ymajorgrids]
\addplot[only marks,mark=*,color=blue,samples=27] (1,{30+20*f(rnd,0.1)});
\addplot[only marks,mark=*,color=green!60!white,samples=27] (2,{20+20*f(rnd,0.1)});
\addplot[only marks,mark=*,color=red,samples=27] (3,{25+20*f(rnd,0.1)});
\addplot[only marks,mark=*,color=purple,samples=27] (4,{15+20*f(rnd,0.1)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are the legend!